# WCF and a winforms application and close

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

If I have a method in which I initialize a WCF proxy and use it, do I also have to call the `Close` method on the proxy before the method ends, or is this taken care of for me?

Comment: Always close. See similar question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792160/when-to-close-wcf-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close it.  Why wait for .Net to do it when you don't know when that will happen for the entire life of the app.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, resources should automatically be closed once they are out of scope.  However, it is usually clearer and more efficient to close it as soon as you don't need it any more.  If it's an `IDisposable` object, you can use a using block to make it simpler:

```
using (MyObj obj = new MyObj())
{
    // do stuff here
}
// now its closed
```

Comment: -1: bad idea to do this with WCF proxies due to a design flaw.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the design flaw is?

Comment: Bad idea to use the "Using" statement with typed clients as you can see here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx