# WCF timeout issue

Tags: silverlight, wcf, timeout

I am new in WCF tech and i am calling this WCF from my silverlight application.

Now, i have one function defined in WCF, this function calls the SP on the database installed on same PC.

This SP takes 1 minute time to execute and return 82000 rows with 50 columns.

I have set the wcf timeout interval to 20 minutes in my application.

Now, when i call this WCF function from my silverlight app it gives me timeout error after 20 minutes. Since the SP takes 1 minute to execute i wonder why this timeout issue is coming?

What can be the thing that is causing the timeout? What can i do to avoid this? I cant implement paging or anything i need to get all this data at one go.

Please help me guys. I have attached my web.config files for your reference also.

**Silverlight web.config file**

```
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ExportServiceRestBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ExportServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ExportServiceBehavior" name="DebtorBal.Web.ExportService1">
            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExportServiceBinding"
                contract="DevExpress.Xpf.Printing.Service.IExportService" />
            <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="ExportServiceRestBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExportServiceRestBinding"
                contract="DevExpress.Xpf.Printing.Service.IExportServiceRest" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExportServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
                transferMode="Streamed">
                <security>
                    <transport realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="myBindingForBigArrays" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security>
                    <transport realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExportServiceRestBinding" transferMode="Streamed" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49261/LsnMonService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingForBigArrays"
            contract="ServiceReference1.ILsnMonService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILsnMonService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**WCF config file**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Check to see if your service is encountering an error - an unhandled error can lead to a timeout on the client side.

Comment: I have checked, no error is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simpler than that.  Do you ever close or dispose of your service?  If not then it's most likely that your service connection is still open.  Once it hits the timeout limit it errors.  Explicitly close the service after you get data back from it.

Comment: I am closing the service. And in fact my first service call is the above one

Comment: A couple of questions: are you getting the results back?  Also, you say this is on a silverlight app so I'm assuming that the call is asyncronous.  At what point do you close the service client?  Can you post the C# code that makes the call to the service?

Comment: Hello, 
Sorry for late reply
No i am not getting the result back. I have used this code to call wcf function
LsnMonWebService objClient = new LsnMonWebService();
            objClient.rpt_deb_ContractGrowthAsync(FromDate);
            objClient.rpt_deb_ContractGrowthCompleted += new EventHandler<rpt_deb_ContractGrowthCompletedEventArgs>(objClient_rpt_deb_ContractGrowthCompleted);

Comment: I am not doing anything else. How to close the service?

Comment: Ok - then I think the problem is that your service is timing out.  You'll see that your service client has a "Close" method.  You should be calling this after the callback event has been fired.  Here's another discussion where the same advice is given:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792160/when-to-close-wcf-client